# Excel Lookup with absolute table reference

Tags: excel, lookup, excel-2016

I am trying to do a Lookup() on  a table of dates (and other info). To do this I have the following function:

```
=LOOKUP(DATE(2016,5,P6), Table1[Date], Table1[Paper Name])
```

where P6 is the day I want to look for. I want to drag this across to other days, but it changes which table column it refers to. I have tried:

```
=LOOKUP(DATE(2016,5,P6), Table1[[Date]:[Date]], Table1[[Paper Name]:[Paper Name]])
```

as suggested by the internet but it gave incorrect results where, if there wasn't a result for that cell, it would just use the last correct match.

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: is it P6 you want to lock? Otherwise, I can't reproduce the error. The formula as you wrote it does not switch table columns for me when I drag over or down.

Comment: P6 is the day I am searching for. I think I found the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the issue. Excel's Lookup function needs sorted data to work, which I did not have (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181201). To fix this I used an INDEX and a MATCH:

```
IFNA(
    INDEX(
        Table1,
        MATCH(
            DATE(2016,MONTH(DATEVALUE($O$2&" 1")),
            P6
        ),
        Table1[[Date]:[Date]],0),6
    ),
    ""
)
```

Comment: Note that you should probably be indicating MATCH(Date....,P6,**0**), because otherwise MATCH is still looking for sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a $ in front of P6:

`=LOOKUP(DATE(2016,5,$P6), Table1[Date], Table1[Paper Name])`

When you copy that to other columns, it will still look to the P column for the date.

Comment: I wanted the P to change, it was the column name that changed